# Install drupal without node module?

Tags: 7, nodes, installation

I know this is achievable in Drupal 8 but is there a way to do this in Drupal 7? I've looked into drupal modules, core files but couldn't find anything reliable. I'm asking this because I might want to have a light installation with custom entities and I don't need Node module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node module is marked as

```
required = TRUE
```

in the node.info file, so the developers are basically saying that as far as they're concerned the node module is imperative for Drupal 7 to function correctly.

You could try patching the info file to remove that line, then disabling the node module to see what happens...in fact if you do that you should write a blog post about it or something, it would be very interesting to find out the effects; I've never heard of anyone trying to do this before :)

Comment: I would add that you'll want to correct other things like the front page's default "node" path, taxonomy.module trying to run functions defined in node.module, etc. I think his best bet is leaving the module installed and then deleting all of the node content types. I can't see node.module making a bootstrap noticeably slower in this instance.

Comment: @Charlie Very good points

Comment: Yes, that actually works, although you have to make some tweaks since it gives an error when installing (with minimal profile) because in common.inc there is a call for node_types_rebuild in drupal_flush_all_caches which is not found. still some tweaks are needed for the installation to work.